# Confused about what Visual Studio 2022 is doing with Git Subtree

Tags: git, visual-studio-2022, git-subtree

Currently using Visual Studio 2022 17.4.4.  I have a Git repo that contains a subtree folder.  Within Visual Studio, the Git Changes window shows two repositories - one for the main repo and another for the subtree.  However, VS does not seem to track changes made in the subtree unless I switch to that repo in the Git Changes window.  From my understanding of subtrees, the contents are supposed to be tracked with the main repo, so I am not sure why Visual Studio is listing it as a separately tracked repo (Note that VSCode Git interface does not behave this way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.  Somehow the subtree folder had a .git folder in it.  Not sure how it got there, but that was causing VS to show it in the Git Changes window.  I re-cloned the repo into a new folder.  After the clone of the main repo, the subtree folder did not have the .git folder in it, which is what I would have expected and VS now doesn't see it as a second repo.

Turns out this was not a VS 2022 problem after all.